# Is AWS Fargate included in their "first year for free" plan?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-fargate

I'm working for a cash-strapped not-yet-startup :D. We want to use Amazon for free to deploy a simple Python REST API endpoint. I was told that Amazon has a "1 year for free" tier. I've built my docker, put it on DockerHub and have successfully deployed it to Fargate.

However, I can't find the Fargate product here in their list of free stuff:

https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all

Yet, according to their own docs, Fargate is ideal for tiny things:

> Tiny workload
> For a small test environment AWS Fargate is a perfect
> fit. It’s generally wasteful to run a tiny test environment on an EC2
> instance because the EC2 instance is too powerful, and you will have a
> hard time getting a good percentage of utilization.

So, should I instead start setting up an EC2 for those 750 hours / month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fargate is not on the free tier list. I suggest you use ECS with a single EC2 instance in the ECS cluster, which will work in a similar way.

Why would it matter if your EC2 instance has low utilization? That's ideal for performance. You can drive slow in a fast car!

Alternately you could also use API Gateway in front of lambda serverless compute. That will probably be cheaper long term. Lambda supports Python.

Comment: Thank you for the Lambda tip. I did see something along those lines. Seemed like a bit of a configuration journey to get it working :). But may be worth it.

Comment: Lambda is fairly easy once you understand it. If you're going to use AWS I strongly suggest you invest in some training. Find AWS Architect Associate from a vendor like Cloud Guru or Adrian Cantrill, as AWS is fairly complex.